# Are basis vectors of an eigenspace themselves eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a linear map, $T:V\to V$, an eigenvalue $\lambda$ it's corresponding eigenspace $A=\lbrace v\in V | T(v)=\lambda v \rbrace$ with basis $\lbrace a_{1}, a_{2},...,a_{n}\rbrace$. Does $T(a_{i})=\lambda a_{i}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_i\in A$ (a basis of a space is always a subset of the space), then by definition, yes, $T(a_i)=\lambda a_i$, since

$$\forall v\in V: (v\in A\iff T(v)=\lambda v)$$

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely: this is exactly **why** one wants to subdivide the space in eigenspaces, so that on those, the operator acts in the most trivial manner, i.e. as multiplication by a scalar.